# Set BigDecimal RoundingMode according to user option without if statements?

Tags: java, android, bigdecimal

I have ~400 statements using `RoundingMode.HALF_UP`, and by the nature of the app, I'd like for the user to be able to choose between the rounding modes. However, I'm at a loss as to how to represent that as a variable, if possible. Because of the incredible amount of statements, I'd like to avoid `if` statements.

**Is it possible to do what I'm asking?**

I've tried an enum, but that's all I could conjure. Everything else got about half a line through. Google hasn't helped. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Perhaps you could use reflection and call the methods at runtime. This might save you 400 case / if/else statements

Comment: I apologize to ask a silly question, but what exactly do you mean by reflection?

Comment: How do you plan to call RoundingMode.HALF_UP ?

Comment: I'd have a class that holds that information. It's only job is to know which rounding method the user has chosen and then provide that information when asked. Something like `myBigDecimal.setScale(2, UsersRoundingMode.getRoundingMode())`

Comment: The user selects two units from two spinners, enters a value that takes the form of a BigDecimal, that divides by another one according to formula, and that's where - `return d.divide(d2, decimals, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toString();`

Comment: @Dan Temple, with the way my project (note Android) is set up, that's quite difficult if not impossible to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
RoundingMode roundingMode = ...;
...
BigDecimal bd3 = bd1.divide(bd2, 2, roundingMode);
```

Comment: I didn't actually realize you could do things like that. Always learning!

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong then you are looking for a mapping between user selection and actual `RoundingMode` object to pass to your calculation. For this `RoundingMode` provides `values()` method that returns all the available `RoundingModes`. You can use these to give your users option to select

```
    RoundingMode[] modes = RoundingMode.values();
    for (RoundingMode roundingMode : modes) {
        System.out.println(roundingMode.name());
    }
```

After selecting a Value you can find out the `RoundingMode` object to use in your calculation by :

```
      RoundingMode.valueOf(String)
```

This will give you corresponding `RoundingMode`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: While the answer from Evgeniy worked, this is quite informative. Thank you.